# Is threre a way to use custom activator for OWIN middlewares?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, owin, owin-middleware

I would like to control the way how OWIN creates registered middlewares. For example when using following code to register `MyCustomMiddleware`:

```
app.Use<MyCustomMiddleware>();
```

I want to be the one who calls `MyCustomMiddleware` constructor and pass all needed arguments. As a motivation please imagine for example following scenarios:

- `MyCustomMiddleware` constructor requires some arguments that should be created based on current request,
- Arguments should be resolved from from DI container,
- I would like to control lifetime of `MyCustomMiddleware`.

I have found out some comments on how to use OWIN with SimpleInjector or Ninject. However I was not able to find anything independent on particular DI library.

Answer (score 2):

```cs
app.Use((c, next) =>
{
    IMiddleware middleware = new MyCustomMiddleware(...);
    return middleware.InvokeAsync(c, _ => next());
});
```

Comment: Thank you, however this will not work for cases when I want to use `app.Use<MyCustomMiddleware>()` or `app.Use(typeof(MyCustomMiddleware))`.

Comment: Either you supply the type and the framework will create the type for you using reflection, or you use the approach I presented here, which allows you to call the constructor yourself. These are your options.